# cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f8bbdc115f0>

Tags: python-3.x, pdf2image

Tried to convert the pdf to an image in colab. It was working fine till yesterday but not working today. Not sure what causes the issue.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob
pdf_dir = glob.glob(r'/content/first_page.pdf')  
img_dir = "/content/" 
for pdf_ in pdf_dir:
   pages = convert_from_path(pdf_, 57)
   pages[0].save('output.'+"jpg", 'JPEG')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by updating sudo

```
!sudo apt-get update
!apt-get install poppler-utils 

# !apt-get install poppler-utils 
# pip install pdf2image


from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdf_dir = glob.glob(r'/content/first_page.pdf')  #your pdf folder path
img_dir = "/content/"           #your dest img path

for pdf_ in pdf_dir:
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_, 500)
    for page in pages:
        page.save(pdf_.split("\\")[-1][:-3]+"jpg", 'JPEG')
```

Now its the pdf is getting converted to image smooth without any issues